# How to get second tag by regex

Tags: regex

I don't understand how to get in the second match `<sub>aaaa</sub>` and not `<sub>eeee</sub>`

my regex:

```
<item>.*?<sub>(.*?)<\/sub>.*?<value>(.*?)<\/value>.*?<\/item>
```

content:

```html
<item> fffffffffffff
<sub>aaaa</sub>
<value>111</value>
</item>

<item>
<sub>eeee</sub> arg34ddddddddddddddd
<atag>ddd</atag>
<sub>aaaa</sub>
<atag>dddg</atag>
<value>222</value>
</item>
```

Can I get it in a step or do I need running a regex several times?

**UPDATE**

I want to get the result like this:

> [ [ 'aaaa', 111],['aaaa', 222] ]

Is it possible?

Comment: What exactly do you want to match ? Do you want to match only `<sub>aaaa</sub>` and that's it ?

Comment: first match: 'aaaa', 111 and second match: 'aaaa', 222

Comment: Just simply match "<sub>.+?</sub>" globally, and fetch index [1]

Comment: XML parsing would seem a lot more appropriate/efficient for this task.

Comment: Are you trying to match `sub` nodes that are followed immediately by a `value` node?

Comment: @revo: Yes, but after `sub` can go another tags(not sub).

Comment: How will you be running this regex? From any particular language? editor?

Comment: Check if this is what you are trying to do https://regex101.com/r/bpsAo9/1

Comment: @Saleem: Let's say Python

Comment: I'll suggest consider using XML parser such as https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html or even https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: @Saleem: Thanks for your time. I'm using the Soup.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
<item>[\s\S]*?<sub>(.*?)<\/sub>((?!<sub>)[\s\S])*<\/item>
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CdEuTl/4/)

This takes only the last `sub` you have between items.

Explanation:

- `<item>[\s\S]*?<sub>` matches lazily anything  between `item` and `sub tags`
- `<sub>(.*?)<\/sub>` matches `sub` tag and captures its content
- `((?!<sub>)[\s\S])*<\/item>` uses [Tempered Greedy Token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/580346) to assure that after the `sub` that was matched before, there is no more `sub` tags before the closing `item` tag

Comment: What if first `<sub>aaaa</sub>` doesn't have a following `<value>`?

Comment: You can make that part optional: `<item>[\S\s]*?<sub>(.*?)<\/sub>[\s\S]*?(<value>(.*?)<\/value>[\S\s]*?)?<\/item>` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CdEuTl/3/) but is it the case in OP problem? If we need to deal with sth more complex (more optional values), I'd better go with XML parser instead.

Comment: That's the point. Requirements are not clear either and in your demo `<sub>eeee</sub>` is matched which shouldn't.